# How to get only first letter from last name of full name?

Tags: swift

I want to get only first letter from last name for privacy of users. Example: "John D."

```
extension String
{
    public func getAcronyms(separator: String = "") -> String
    {
        let acronyms = self.components(separatedBy: " ").map({ String($0.characters.first!) }).joined(separator: separator);
        return acronyms;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are cultures where the family name is placed first. And even “western” names can be difficult to handle correctly: ["Johann Heinrich Tischbein the Younger"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Heinrich_Tischbein_the_Younger)

Comment: There must be a way to handle it. Because I don't want to public people's full name.

Comment: If you want to as accurately as possible represent of the components of a person’s name I'd recommend that you look at [PersonNameComponentsFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/personnamecomponentsformatter).

Comment: How about asking the user how they want their name to be shown in situations where privacy is a concern and keeping that as a separate data item?

Comment: I already added an option to hide his/her name if they want to hide. However, in default, I only want to show his/her name as John D. or J. Doe if possible.

Comment: The obvious solution would be to separate first and last name into different properties.

Comment: when you receive the full name, make sure the user input first name then last name, (for example: use two TextFields) and concatenate their texts

Comment: [Be careful when making assumptions about people's names.](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: How will you abbreviate a chinese name?

Comment: My app will serve only for local people. @Sulthan

Comment: Does that mean there are no people with asian names in your area? I am pretty sure you will be surprised

Comment: I will think about it. Thank you for your concerns about Asian names.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For proper naming, you have to use `PersonNameComponentsFormatter.`

```
let name =  "Joe Singh"
let nameFormatter = PersonNameComponentsFormatter()
if let nameComps  = nameFormatter.personNameComponents(from: name), let firstLetter = nameComps.givenName?.first, let lastName = nameComps.familyName {

     let sortName = "\(firstLetter). \(lastName)"  // J. Singh
 }
```

You can also find:

```
nameComps.middleName
nameComps.familyName
nameComps.nameSuffix 
nameComps.namePrefix
```

And also can configured the format of your names

```
Default
short
long 
abbreviated
```